# Making sense of this proof for the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality

Tags: proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I was working my way through de La Fuente's *Mathematical Methods and Models for Economists* for fun in my spare time.

Towards the start of the second chapter we are presented with a proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality of the following form:
$(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i)^2\leq(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2)(\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2)$.

We are then told to conisder the following identity:
$\sum^n_{i=1}(\alpha_i-\lambda\beta_i)^2\geq0$

Trivially, expanding, this gives us: $\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2-2\lambda\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i+\lambda^2\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2\geq0$

Then when we let $\lambda=\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i}{\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2}$, we get:

$\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2-2\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i}{\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2}\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i+(\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i}{\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2})^2\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2\geq0$

$\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2-\frac{(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i)^2}{\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2}\geq0$

Finally, rearranging, we get:

$(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2)(\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2)\geq(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i)^2$

Of course, we can also take the square root of both sides to get: $\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i}\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i}\geq\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i$

Admittedly, while it is abundantly clear how each line follows from the next, I am still rather lost on what exactly is going on. My limited mathematical intuition tells me that the proof holds because it holds for any value of $\lambda$ given the first identity we are told to consider. Hence, it just so happens that when we substitute our special value for $\lambda$ we are coincidentally(?) able to derive the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

However, even if this is the case (and I would very much appreciate being corrected here if I am wrong as well), while I certainly do not dispute the correctness of the identity, I have no idea where on Earth it is coming from!

Is there some special mathematical skill I need to be able to come up with such a starting identity and derive Cauchy-Schwarz from it? Is there some underlying mathematical property which I am unaware of? Is there some way I could use the idea in this proof to demonstrate other mathematical concepts, or is this just a one off?

To be perfectly honest, I feel as though I have witnessed some mystical mathematical magic, and any help at demystification would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your formula $$(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i)^2\leq(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i)^2(\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i)^2$$ is not Cauchy-Schwarz.  It should be $$(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i)^2\leq(\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2)(\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2)$$  The proof magically switches from one to the other with the reason "rearranging".

Comment: @GEdgar just fixed it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach this step: $$\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i^2-2\lambda\sum^n_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i+\lambda^2\sum^n_{i=1}\beta_i^2\geq0$$

you are dealing with the quadratic $f(\lambda)=a \lambda^2 + b\lambda + c$ on the left hand side, where $a = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i ^2, b = -2\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \beta_i, c=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i ^2$.

The condition tells you that $f(\lambda) \geq 0$ for all $\lambda$. You can check that the minimum value of $f(\lambda)=a\lambda^2+b\lambda +c$ is attained at $\lambda = \frac{-b}{2a}$ by differentiation, or by completing the square and seeing that $f(\lambda) = a(\lambda + \frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}+c$. If the inequality is true for all $\lambda$, then it must be true for the choice of $\lambda$ that minimises $f(\lambda)$ in particular. This is the motivation for the choice of $\lambda$. Thinking geometrically, $f(\lambda) \geq 0$ tells us that the parabola lies above the $x$-axis (possibly touching the $x$-axis), and so in particular the vertex of the parabola must also be above or on the $x$-axis.

Another way to think of things, which is really the same way, is to consider the discriminant of $f(\lambda)$. If $f(\lambda) \geq 0$, then the discriminant $D = b^2-4ac$ must satisfy $D \leq 0$. This also leads to the result.